# All arguments must have same length ERROR in R

Tags: r, function

When I try and run the below code I get the error:

> Error in table(GD_DATA$Area.x, GD_DATA$Input) :
>     all arguments must have the same length

It works fine when I run it by itself (i.e not part of a function) but I want to be able to run it in the function to make the code more efficient/readable.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

When I run the code outside of a function it produces a table of the amount of children as columns and the area as rows, with the value in the cell representing the amount of households with a certain amount of children in each area.

Code where it errors:

```
 Frequencies<- function(column, df){
 df = as.data.frame.matrix(table(GD_DATA$Area.x, GD_DATA$column))
 }
Frequencies(No.Of.Children, No_Child)
```

Next code runs fine and giving the correct output:

```
No_Child<-as.data.frame.matrix(table(GD_DATA$Area.x, GD_DATA$No.Of.Children))
```

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Frequencies<- function(Input){
 output = as.data.frame.matrix(table(GD_DATA$Area.x, GD_DATA[[Input]])
 }
Frequencies("No.Of.Children")
```

- The argument No_child does not seem to be used in your function.
- When you use GD_DATA$Input, you are trying to get column Input from the dataframe, and not the value of Input. (hope that explanation is clear)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I still get the same error, also that way I wouldn't be able to define the output which needs to be different every time.

Comment: That is not necessary. Maybe see: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-and-debug-an-r-function/

Comment: If you want the output to be into `No_Child` you would write `No_Child <- Frequencies("No.Of.Children")`

Comment: No_Child Is the name of the output dataframe. I've tried to make the changes you suggested but I still get the same error about all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Please visit the URL's G. Grothendieck prvided, so we can help you.

Comment: It worked using [[Input]] instead of [Input] thanks!

Comment: Great, happy that you were able to resolve your problem, sorry for the mistake in my answer!